# What is the exact term for the way Tarzan speak in such sentences as "Me Tarzan, you Jane"?

Tags: terminology

In countries where English is not a native language, you hear people speak with no conjunctions, no verb conjugations, no adjectives nor adverbs. Examples: You come my house. I cook chicken. We eat chicken. After eat we sleep my bed.

Comment: I don't know an exact term for "non-linguist's imaginary idea of how a man raised by apes would speak"

Comment: But I think you are talking about a [pidgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin) (of which, confusingly, [Tok Pisin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tok_Pisin) is _not_ an example).

Comment: This is a rendering of the language of the Great Apes. who raised Tarzan, according to Edgar Rice Burroughs (the definitive reference).

Answer (score 2):

As @ColinFine notes in the comments, this looks like a [Pidgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin).

> The world's most famous pidgin language speaker is Tarzan. When he says 'Me Tarzan, you Jane,' he uses a simplified version of English.

(source: [Language Myths, by Laurie Bauer](https://books.google.nl/books?id=-3YokgYKoJMC&pg=PT103&lpg=PT103&dq=pidgin+tarzan&source=bl&ots=2hLQn2BKP6&sig=ACfU3U0AiER6_6fpoCNJOL4NGo9Twsjmag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiopre1_KnpAhUD2aQKHXzRB_AQ6AEwAnoECBAQAQ#v=onepage&q=pidgin%20tarzan&f=false))

Wikipedia defines it as

> a grammatically simplified means of communication that develops between two or more groups that do not have a language in common: typically, its vocabulary and grammar are limited and often drawn from several languages.

That isn't particularly true in the (fictive) case of Tarzan, but, as noted in  [The English Language: A Guided Tour of the Language by David Crystal](https://books.google.nl/books?id=rZ1b3iU3pW4C&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=pidgin+tarzan&source=bl&ots=qbi_yxUdYj&sig=ACfU3U10H9PPtqV1glOCGHEMEXSGjQTTEA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNyeL5_anpAhWL-qQKHSfVA4IQ6AEwA3oECBEQAQ#v=onepage&q=pidgin%20tarzan&f=false) notes, "Tarzan's style is not very far from reality".